# How do I click on an element available in a specific row where dynamic row is added?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide

In the below pic, I need to click on the icon in a row which is newly added and column1 value is stored as global variables.

Have used the below code, unable to find a solution.
        WebElement userListTable = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='KendoActiveCorpUserGrid']/div[2]/table"));

```
    List<WebElement> rows_table = userListTable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='KendoActiveCorpUserGrid']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr"));

    int rows_count = rows_table.size();

    for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++){
        if(ResultName.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(globalVariables.NewCorpUserName)){

        }
    }
```

Need to click on element id avaialble in that row:

```
//*[@id="CGOLK90700779C"]/span/span/i[3]
```

**ResultName** is the position for which variable is stored globally.

[image]

Comment: Is the problem that the test doesn't wait for the element to appear?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++){
        if(ResultName.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(globalVariables.NewCorpUserName)){ }
 }
```

Here, you are just performing the same check (*if*) rows_count number of times.

You need to perform the check on each row, rather than on these global variables.

```
// Finding the table
WebElement table = userListTable.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='KendoActiveCorpUserGrid']/div[2]/table"));

waitTargetTextToBeOnTheTable(table, globalVariables.NewCorpUserName);

//Finding all rows
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody tr"));

// Finding the first row that matches our criterea 
WebElement targetRow = rows.stream().findFirst(
                           row -> row.findElement(PLACE_HERE_THE_LOCATOR_OF_THE_USERS_COLUMN).getText().equals(globalVariables.NewCorpUserName).get();

// Find the icon inside the row
WebElement icon = row.findElement(By.ByXPath, "//span/span/i[3]");

// Interact with the icon
icon.click();
```

Replace *PLACE_HERE_THE_LOCATOR_OF_THE_USERS_COLUMN* with the proper locator, and you will perform the check on each *Users* column, in order to identify the row.

*waitTargetTextToBeOnTheTable* would be as simple as:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(targetElement, targetValue));
```

Comment: By.ID, "CGOLK90700779C" wont work on 2nd run, CGOLK90700779C is dynamic. Thnks!

Comment: Could you share a HTML snippet of the <table> node (and its sub-nodes)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answer and valuable feedbacks!

I finally found solution putting elementid.gettext() inside xpath. It worked fine.

```
for (int row = 0; row <=rows_count; row++){
        if(ResultName.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(globalVariables.NewCorpUserName)){
            Log.message("Corp User present in the list and Name found as: "+ResultName.getText());
            String InviteIcon = "//td[contains(text(),'"+ResultName.getText()+"')]/../td[8]/div[2]//span//i[3]";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(InviteIcon)).click();
        }
        break;
    }
```